# Creating character for lumbaryard

Tags: character, 3d-modeling, character-development

What I need to do if I want to create character for cryengine/lumbaryard?

Comment: Welcome to Game Development Stackexchange. Please note that we are a question&answer community. We are not a job board. If you want to hire someone, then you are wrong here. If, on the other hand, you have a question about game development, feel free to ask it.

Comment: I wanted to know if someone can help me by showing me the way to do it. I AM NOT OFFERING ANYONE TO DO IT FOR ME. I want someone to show me the way. I will do the operation by my self cause I will feel free if I can do it by myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest way to create a character to import into CryEngine or Lumberyard is to create a 3d model in [Blender](http://www.blender.org), put in a skeleton, animate it, and then import it into CryEngine or Lumberyard.

If you intend to create a humanoid character, you can check out [MakeHuman](http://www.makehuman.org).

There are a number of great tutorials on YouTube, which I suggest you search instead of asking here on StackExchange.

Hope this helps you!